# Serve default page for all subdirs of URL

Tags: http, go, url, gorilla, mux

I would like to call `FileServer` in such way, that it serves the same page for all subdirectories of distinct directories (`subdirs`).

The naïve approach, of course, does not work:

```
  for _, prefix := range subdirs {
     fsDist := http.FileServer(http.Dir(defaultPage))
     r.PathPrefix(prefix).Handler(http.StripPrefix(prefix, fsDist))
  }
```

Because `/abc/123` is mapped to `defaultPage/123` and I need just `defaultPage`.

For example, if `subdirs := []string{"abc", "xyz"}`, it should be mapped like this:

```
    abc/xyz => defaultPage
    abc/def => defaultPage
    xyz/aaa => defaultPage
```

I understand that I need something like `http.SetPrefix` or something like that, but there is nothing of that kind. Of course, I could write my own handler, but I wonder what is the standard approach here?

The task is pretty common, and I suppose there should be some standardized approach?

Comment: It's not clear if your question is about `FileServer` specifically or HTTP servers in general. Can you please clarify with a minimal, reproducible example per https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example ?

Comment: @EliBendersky: clarified it a little bit. I understand how to write it with my own handler function, but maybe it is possible to do it with `FileServer`

Comment: @mh-cbon: No; simply return the same file for all queries with some prefix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**: multiple-route support & static file-serving:

---

It sounds like you just want:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/products", ProductsHandler) // some other route...

staticFilePath := "catch-all.txt"

fh := http.HandlerFunc(
    func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        http.ServeFile(w, r, staticFilePath)
    },
)

for _, dir := range []string{"abc", "xyz"} {
    r.PathPrefix("/" + dir + "/").Handler(fh)
}
```

Working example (run outside playground): https://play.golang.org/p/MD1Tj1CUcEh

```
$ curl localhost:8000/abc/xyz
catch all

$ curl localhost:8000/abc/def
catch all

$ curl localhost:8000/xyz/aaa
catch all

$ curl localhost:8000/products
product
```

Comment: Yes, almost, the only question that I want to return a file. I understand that I could just open the file, read and return its content inside `catchAll`, but would be possible to server it with a standard `FileServer`?

Comment: To serve a single file, use [http.ServeFile](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeFile). Updated answer to reflect this usage.

Comment: Exactly what I needed!